# Array of struct/map without keys

Tags: json, go

Welcome all.
Tell me how to get a flat array in GO.
That is, conditionally, I have a structure without keys of the form:

```
type DashboardHeatMapStruct struct {
    float64
    string
}
```

Next, I give it in response to rest in the form of JSON and get output of the form:

```
[[0,"#AEAEAE"],[0.01,"#0e00ff"],[0.65,"#00ffcf"],[0.7,"#00ffcf"],[0.75,"#00ff9c"],[0.8,"#00ff0a"],[0.85,"#b3ff00"],[0.9,"#ffdc00"],[0.95,"#ff6d00"],[1,"#c60000"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare a struct type to represent the elements of the JSON array.

```
type DashboardHeatMapStruct struct {
    t float64
    c string
}
```

Implement the [json.Unmarshaler](https://godoc.org/encoding/json#Unmarshaler) interface on that type:

```
func (d *DashboardHeatMapStruct) UnmarshalJSON(p []byte) error {
    // p is expected to be JSON array with float and 
    // string values. Create slice to match.
    v := []interface{}{&d.t, &d.c}

    // Unmarshal to JSON array to the slice. The JSON decoder
    // follows the pointers in the slice to set the struct members.
    return json.Unmarshal(p, &v)
}
```

Implement the [json.Marshler](https://godoc.org/encoding/json#Marshaler) interface to encode back to JSON.

```
func (d DashboardHeatMapStruct) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    v := []interface{}{d.t, d.c}
    return json.Marshal(v)
}
```

Unmarshal to a slice of DashboardHeatMapStruct:

```
var result []DashboardHeatMapStruct
if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &result); err != nil {
    // handle error
}
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/pQ18d271J3q).

Comment: It's getting data, but i think to generate and send it in json.